# Access multiple SSH-controllable boxes centrally

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding, remote-access

I have a few SSH boxes running on an ESXi Host, of which I would like to access from outside my normal home network.

Rather than port forwarding and pointing to all sorts of different VM's, is there any way to access them from a central location?

I was thinking of setting up a super-thin BSD guest with nothing but SSH, and remote to that. Then using the "ssh" command, connect from within my network, resolving internal hostnames without reinitialising a new connection to my client box in the big mean outside world.

The other was creating a VPN (of which I have done, albeit with troubles, via OpenVPN) and doing it that way, but I think the VPN for quick SSH seems a bit bloated, and sometimes I like to SSH with my droid on the go of which I dont want to fiddle with OpenVPM apps.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Install netcat and sshd on a single machine that has been port-forwarded to, and then use [`ProxyCommand`](https://superuser.com/search?q=[ssh]+proxycommand) on the client to create a tunnel through that machine to each of the others.

Comment: So basically, this will redirect ports from one machine to another? If I forward, say, port x to the "hub", and use `nc` to cross between the port on the "hub", to the "node" over a standard port 22 SSH, I should then use this port x as the pathway for the new Putty connection?